# Do Game Boys lose their CE certification if modified?

Tags: european-union, regulations

On the Game Boy color and Game Boy Advance I found the CE sign.

I think this sign is mandatory and without it they may not be sold in the EU (at least commercially).

For both of these 2 models there are commercial shops which modify the Game Boys by replacing the display, modifying the electronic, adding LEDs or adding a lithium battery. Then they sell the modified device.

I wonder if the devices lose their certification making it illegal to sell them (at least commercially).

You can find suchs [mods on eBay.de](https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_nkw=gba%20mod) for example.

I think SE law is the right site as discussed for a similar question on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381935/where-can-i-ask-about-the-legality-of-printing-the-nintendo-logo-and-trademarks#comment1273920_381935).

Edit: I think it might be the same for the FCC sign of the Game Boy Classic in the USA.

Comment: One would need to check what CE rules the devices need to adhere to (difficult to find out, because there are a zillion different rules for all possible devices). The most relevant ones I am aware of are only about devices connected to AC power, so they wouldn't be applicable to a Game Boy.